# Why does CLT converge quadratically?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, central-limit-theorem, reinforcement-learning

CLT states that the standard deviation of the error falls as
1/sqrt(N), where N is the number of trials. Why does this imply that the convergence is quadratic?

In particular, I am confused about this passage from Sutton & Barto's Reinforcement Learning book:

[image]

Comment: Sounds weird.would check another book.

Answer (score 2):

Let us define
$$ S = \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \right) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1) $$

We can use Edgeworth series to approximate the probability distribution in terms of cumulants:
$$ G(x) = P(S \leqslant x) = \Phi(x) + n^{-1/2}p(x) \phi(x) + O(n^{-1}) $$

where $\Phi(x)$ is the cdf of the normal distribution, $\phi(x)$ its pdf and $p(x)$ is an even quadratic polynomial of $x$.

The leading term if we substract the true CDF of the normal distribution is $n^{-1/2} = 1/\sqrt{n}$, therefore the CLT converges with a rate of $\sim n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Yes: but to almost all the world, "quadratic" convergence is $O(n^{-2}),$ not $O(n^{-1/2}).$  That is the crux of the matter.